# How to decode json file in php?

Tags: php, json

I want to get the data from json.
My json file is like this

```
[[["test demo","",,,0]],,"vi",,,,0.58984375,,[["vi"],,[0.58984375]]]
```

I want to get the data "test demo" so i create code like this

```
$html = file_get_contents("jasonfile");
$obj1 = json_decode($html, true);

echo $obj1[][][];
```

but it does not working.
what i am doing wrong please help me on this..

Comment: The content of the file is not valid JSON and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not valid, it doesn't allow several commas in row. Changing it to:

```
[[["test demo","",0]],"vi",0.58984375,[["vi"],[0.58984375]]]
```

And running:

```
$obj1 = json_decode(...yourinput...); echo $obj1[0][0][0];
```

correctly outputs `test demo`.

Comment: Its the same as my answer!

Comment: you answer doesn't explain what the error actually is, so this answer is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[["test demo","","","",0]],"","vi","","","",0.58984375,"",[["vi"],"",[0.58984375]]]


$html = file_get_contents("jasonfile");
$obj1 = json_decode($html, true);

echo $obj1[0][0][0];
```